# how to make a pop up appear only once in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup, local-storage

i have my age verification pop up i want to appear only once when the site is visited and the pop up keeps appearing each item i refresh my browser, how do i go about it? answer will be much appreciated.

```
if (document.getElementById("newsletter-popup-form")) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var mpInstance = $.magnificPopup.instance;
    if (mpInstance.isOpen) {
      mpInstance.close();
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: "#newsletter-popup-form",
        },
        type: "inline",
        removalDelay: 350,
        callbacks: {
          open: function () {
            $("body").css("overflow-x", "visible");
            $(".sticky-header.fixed").css("padding-right", "1.7rem");
          },
          close: function () {
            $("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
            $(".sticky-header.fixed").css("padding-right", "0");
          },
        },
      });
    }, 500);
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: you could save the age they input to local cache. Then on page reload, check the local cache to see if that variable has a value, and if no value is found, the popup can be output at that point... at least that's what I would do.

Comment: also, the if statement in this situation isn't doing much. Essentially its saying right now, do you find the element within the html (whether displayed or not displayed). With the set timeout you have, its still going to find it in your code even without the end user seeing it in the Dom. unfortunately I'm not so great with JQuery, but ill try my best to at least make a template and you can add your JQuery to it...

Comment: cookies, local storage or database

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<!--(place this inside the popup)-->
<input id="age-input" />
```

**JS**

```
const popup = document.getElementById("newsletter-popup-form")
const ageInput = document.getElementById("age-input")

ageInput.addEventListener(change, (e) => {
  localStorage['userAge'] = ageInput.value;
}

if if (localStorage.getItem("userAge") === null) { {
   // shows the popup on refresh so long as variable is not found
   popup.style.display="block";
   //insert any additional code here...
} else {
   // hides the popup
   popup.style.display="none";
}
```